# How to update a QTableView when its database was changed

Tags: c++, mysql, database, model-view-controller, qt

What's the standard way of updating a QTableView when its database (MySQL) was changed (outside of the model be it QSqlRelationalTableModel or QSqlTableModel)?

Right now I'm thinking of using a QTimer and update the view only if the database was changed (probably by querying a time stamp).

Answer (score -1):

[QSqlTableModel::beforeInsert](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsqltablemodel.html#beforeInsert) and related signals may help.

Not sure if they capture modifications made outwith the Qt API though.

Comment: Yes, there's no emitted signal when the modification is made outside Qt.